# Git issue - git archive handling files with space in their names

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I am having trouble while handling `filenames` having space in them.

I use the below piece of `script` to fetch the files contained in a `push onto` a folder in a `zip` format and later `unzip` the files.

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d /apps/sample/XXXX)

while read oldrev newrev refname
do

commits=`git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev`
for commit in $commits
do
     git diff-tree -z --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit | xargs -0 git archive -o     $tempdir/list.zip HEAD:
     unzip $tempdir/list.zip -d $scandir
     rm -rf /apps/sample/list.zip
done
done
exit 0
```

In the below example, I added and committed the file `SAMPLE FILE.txt`.
The thing is when `git archive` command encounters a space, i get the error below.

```
[root@inba2 repo]# git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 296 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: fatal: path not found: SAMPLE FILE.txt
remote: Archive:  /apps/sample/l7Im/list.zip
remote:   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
remote:   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
remote:   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
remote:   the last disk(s) of this archive.
remote: unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /apps/sample/l7Im/list.zip or
remote:         /apps/sample/l7Im/list.zip.zip, and cannot find         /apps/sample/l7Im/list.zip.ZIP, period
```

> git version is 1.7.1
>
> bash version is 4.1.2

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like an issue with the `unzip` command. Can you try commenting the unzip command in the script and check if the **push** works?

Comment: Also which git-hook is this script registered as?...

Comment: git hook is for pre-receive.. server side hook..I beleive the error is with the zip command for SAMPLE TEXT.txt file "fatal: path not found: SAMPLE FILE.txt".

Comment: I just tested it out and zip fails to recognize the filename with space.. Please let me know, if you find any solution for this.. Thank you..  :)

Comment: Set the following variable on both the git-server and git-client machine prior to attempting the push. `GIT_TRACE=/home/<username>/git.log` This should enable logging all internal and external commands run by `git` The log file will contain some useful info about what's going wrong behind the scenes.

Comment: Also does the command work properly if run on the shell manually by specifying the commit-id or does it fail outside of a hook context as well?

Comment: Also since you simply seem to be copying all the modified files into $scandir, you could simply try `list = git diff-tree -z --no-commit-id --name-only -r $commit` and `for each item in $list` run `cp $item $scandir/$item`.

Comment: ok, the problem is with the zip command.. A usual push of the file with space in its name does work.. it looks like xargs is not considering space in between filename..

Comment: I tried with the -I{} option and i get all the files in the repository :(.. Please help